# What is a "multinomial model" in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

What is the mathematical definition of "multinomial model" in machine learning?
I will be happy for a good definition plus an example.

Comment: Are you asking in neural network or Random Forest?

Answer (score 0):

A multinomial model is the statistical terminology for counting n repeated draws according to a softmax classifier (regressor to be precise).

Update after @David comment:
Categorical and multinomial distribution are used interchangeably ( technically incorrect though), as often in practice what is unknown is the probability vector p, but not the sample size n.  Also for ML models at inference time n is usually known (e.g. n=1 for predicting the next sample).  So the learning problem is to map features X to a probability vector p over K categories, e.g. through a softmax last layer.

This is analogous to how when dealing with binomial outcomes (counts), practitioners refer to binomial vs Bernoulli problem setup interchangeably as also here often n is known / fixed, whereas the probability of p(y=1|X) is unknown and has to be learned through e.g. a sigmoid (logistic) regression setup.

See also
https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/multilevel-categorical-multinomial-model-terms-and-priors/5294

https://beginningwithml.wordpress.com/2018/06/22/3-4-softmax-regression/

Comment: Not quite. Softmax would be the same as a categorical distribution. Multinomial is a generalisation of the binomial distribution.

Comment: @David in ml context of prediction models at inference time ppl are interested in the prediction of a known "n" ( e.g. n=1).  So yes I incorrectly put softmax as the equivalence to multinomial, but in (ml/predictuve) practice ppl usually mean the instance level inference where n Is assumed to be known/given (n=1 or sample size) and all that had to be learned is the probability vector just like for binomial models it's common to learn "p" , not also n.  Will update comment to clarify and add references